# open source DMS Jackrabbit/modeshape/nuxeo

Tags: jackrabbit, dms, nuxeo, modeshape, jackrabbit-oak

I'm looking for open source DMS/EDM solution.

So i'm seeing :

1. Jackrabbit

   - project seems dead
2. Modeshape:

   - The documentation seems quite good
   - But the project is dead ? I haven't seen push in master since 9 month ago : https://github.com/ModeShape/modeshape
   - Default rest api seems succinct.
3. Jackrabbit oak:

   - I'm little bit confused by the documentation.
   - I didn't see rest-api?
4. Nuxeo

   - They seems have everything that i need.
   - Their rest-api appears to me good?
   - But i didn't understead if it's free or not.

I think, this kind of question was done almost 7 years ago: [What does ModeShape offer that JackRabbit doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392815/what-does-modeshape-offer-that-jackrabbit-doesnt)

So what it is your opinion on this subject ? Did i miss something ?
 
Do you known others solutions?
 
Do you known if one is better than others?

Answer (score 0):

Nuxeo is Open Source and is free for use. Nuxeo customers pay for [support and additional services](https://www.nuxeo.com/services/).

Answer (score 0):

Jackrabbit "classic" is in maintenance mode. Jackrabbit Oak is very active.

Regarding the documentation: what exactly are you looking for? In doubt, mail the users mailing list.

Regarding HTTP API: there are various ways to expose Oak over HTTP, such as using Apache Sling or Jackrabbit WebDAV...